# Convert currency with commas into numeric

Tags: r, formatting, currency, numeric

I have a column in a dataframe as follows:

```
COL1
$54,345
$65,231
$76,234
```

How do I convert it into this:

```
COL1
54345
65231
76234
```

The way I tried it at first was:

```
df$COL1<-as.numeric(as.character(df$COL1))
```

That didn't work because it said NA's were introduced.

Then I tried it like this:

```
df$COL1<-as.numeric(gsub("\\$","",as.character(df$COL1)))
```

And the same this happened.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The reason why the `gsub` didn't work was there was `,` in the column, which is still non-numeric.  So when convert to 'numeric' with `as.numeric`, all the non-numeric elements are converted to `NA`.  So, we need to remove both `,` and `$` to make it work.

```
df1$COL1 <- as.numeric(gsub('[$,]', '', df1$COL1))
```

We match the `$` and `,` inside the square brackets (`[$,]`) so that it will be considered as that character (`$` left alone has special meaning i.e. it signifies the end of the string.) and replace it with `''`.

Or we can escape (`\\`) the character (`$`) to match it and replace by `''`.

```
df1$COL1 <- as.numeric(gsub('\\$|,', '', df1$COL1))
```

Comment: This works great with positive numbers but does not seem to work for negative currency. For example, after I run the code, all positives work but negative like this, ($100,00.04), does not.

Comment: @AlexS.Sandoval is there a `-` sign before that?

Comment: No. the source of the data is formatted to show negative currency in parenthesis.

Comment: @AlexS.Sandoval regex is based on patterns.  Here, the parenthesis is not included.  If you include that it should work

Comment: To take care of negative currency represented by enclosing parentheses try this before the call to as.numeric:  `df1$COL1 <- as.numeric(gsub('[$,)]', '', df1$COL1)); 
 df1$COL1 <- sub('[(]', '-', df1$COL1`

Answer (score 55):

We could use `parse_number` from `readr` package which removes any non-numeric characters.

```
library(readr)
parse_number(df$COL1)
#[1] 54345 65231 76234
```

Comment: `parse_number()` has its drawbacks: `c("1,23", "134")` will yield `123, 134` .

Comment: @SebastianSauer If you expected 1.23 then you can pass locale separately. `readr::parse_number(c("1,23", "134"),  locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","))`

Comment: doesn't work well with negative numbers, at least In my example

Answer (score 1):

Another option using stringr library to remove '$' and ',' then convert as follows:

```
df %>% mutate(COL1 = COL1 %>% str_remove_all("\\$,") %>% as.numeric())
```

Comment: Rather, df %>% mutate(COL1 = COL1 %>% str_remove_all("[$,]") %>% as.numeric())

Answer (score 0):

Nested gsub to handle negatives and transform to make it functional and to take advantage of NSE

```
transform(df, COL1 = as.numeric(gsub("[$),]", "", gsub("^\\(", "-", COL1))))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it