# Converting "1000,00+" values to numeric in R gives warning "NAs introduced by coercion"?

Tags: r, replaceall

My dataset has column "Installs" which has values like ("5,000+", "10,000+", .... )

When I try to convert it to numeric, it gives me NA values with an error:

```
df <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",df_dataset$Installs))

Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

I want to replace both "+" and "," symbols. How can I acheive that?

Comment: `readr::parse_number(c("5,000+", "10,000+"))`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944103/convert-currency-with-commas-into-numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing all non numeric characters:

```r
Installs_Numeric <- as.numeric(gsub("[,+]+", "", df_dataset$Installs))
```

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this as correct answer.